# Query example - safe or not for sql injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I have a short question - is code below vulnerable for sql injection in any version of PHP?

```
$A = $_GET['A'];
$B = 10;
$q = "SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE name = 'admin' LIMIT ".($A*$B).",$B";
$res = mysql_query($q);
...
```

I saw that kind of code on my client website and got me to think... but couldn't find any attack vector :)

Comment: It is safe, only `$A` is from the user, and it is multiplied by `$B` in the request...

Comment: Not in this 1 example. Since you are using `mysql_*` it would be surprising if you didn't have an injection somewhere.

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql, it's recommended to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is SQL safe, as the variable $A is being multiplied by an integer $B. However, all GET variables store string values, so it would be smart to typecast $A to an integer, like so:

```
$A = intval($_GET['A']);
```

OR

```
$A = (int) $_GET['A'];
```

You should also switch to the method `mysqli_query()`, as `mysql_query()` is deprecated.

Comment: ... or `$A = (int) $_GET['A'];`

Comment: This isn't his own code, he said he saw it in a client's site.

Comment: @Barmar Well, same goes for his client :D

Comment: Guys, I know how it should be done, just wondering if that particular example is secure :) Thanks for help!